# How to use egg to install scikit-image?

Tags: python, windows, installation, scikit-image

I am stuck on this installation of scikit-image (aka skimage). I tried multiple ways:

- Installation from a git hub folder (using the requirements.txt)
- Installation from a [whl file](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs)
- Installation with pip install scikit-image

All three trials failed during the import: import skimage

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'geometry'
It seems that scikit-image has not been built correctly.

Your install of scikit-image appears to be broken.
Try re-installing the package following the instructions at:
https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/install.html
```

I went through internet but did not find solutions besides the ones above.
Does anyone went through that before?
One possibility seems to be to pip install with -egg, but I found that for Mac rather than Windows.

**EDIT:**

Hi everyone, so I found a solution but this is kind of very hard and I still don't understand why it did not work before.

I just:

- uninstall anaconda
- uninstall python
- install python (3.8)
- install Anaconda (I have trouble with Spyder now^^)

Comment: If there isn't a specific requirement to use above methods you can easily use `Anaconda` to install skimage.

Comment: @B200011011 You mean installing Anaconda and scikit image will come along? I learnt that method after asking the question, but now that I uninstalled and reinstalled I have trouble putting Anaconda at work

Comment: Please check if my answer below helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code for `computer vision/Image processing/machine learning` tasks, then it can be done in pycharm with conda environment very easily. There is **no need** to install python separately to run Anaconda.

First, download and install `pycharm`. Next, If you use windows then download `Anaconda 64 bit python 3.7` version from here,
https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#windows

You can find some details about managing environment and helpful links here,
[How to create some environments for tensorflow in anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745202/how-to-create-some-environments-for-tensorflow-in-anaconda)

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Create a conda environment first using Anaconda Prompt command line,

```
conda create -n cvenv python=3.7
```

Now activate that environment using. By default base is activated.

```
conda activate cvenv
```

Next, install the packages you want,

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-image
conda install -c conda-forge pillow
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

I use `conda-forge` packages as they are more recent. Finally, open pycharm and create a new project by selecting existing python interpreter in conda environment. If none exists then select,

```
Browse > Add Python Interpreter > Conda Environment > Interpreter > Browse > Anaconda3 installation folder > envs folder > cvenv folder > Python.exe
```

You can test by creating a python file and writing `import skimage`.